# URL Rewrite with Web.config

Tags: .net

I need to rewrite the URL :

http://www.mydomain.com/test.aspx?pagename=quotes&companycode=324543
To
http://www.mydomain.com/test/quotes/324543

I am Using IIS 7.5 and VS 2008.

I need the Rule code to written in web.config.

Comment: Your question will be better received by the community if you "show your work."  What have you tried so far, and why didn't it work for you?

Comment: Hi senthilramasubbu.
You might also want to update the title of the question to better reflect that the question is asking about URL rewriting rather than simply listing the technologies you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Wizard in the IIS GUI here's the redirect and corresponding rewrite rule. It may not be exactly what you want, but should give you a good idea.

```
            <rule name="RedirectUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^test\.aspx$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^pagename=([^=&amp;]+)&amp;companycode=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}/{C:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="test.aspx?pagename={R:1}&amp;companycode={R:2}" />
            </rule>
```

Comment: I tried with first rule, page is redirecting like http://localhost:1324/test/Quotes/2345623.00 but page is showing 404 error means page not found. Here test.aspx is in root and getting pages from test sub folder.